# activejdbc association between 2 models

Tags: java, activejdbc

I'm have a database with the following 2 tables.

**Table 1**

`CREATE TABLE players (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(255),
    lastName VARCHAR(255),
    birthDate DATE,
    position VARCHAR(255),
    id_teams INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_teams) REFERENCES teams(id)
);`

**Table 2**

`CREATE TABLE teams (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

I also have the models Team and Player extending Model in my java project. I can add teams and players to the database but I don't understand how to add a player to a team without inserting the foreign key manually.

I've tried something like :

`teams.get(0).addPlayer("Thomas", "Miller", new Date(2020, 0, 7), "Forward");`

but that gives me the error

`No association from model 'class sportstats.domain.Team' to model 'class sportstats.domain.Player'.`

Any tips how I can think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see ActiveJDBC documentation here: https://javalite.io/one_to_many_associations

The column  `players.id_teams` should  be  called `players.team_id`, then it will work.

Comment: Do you know the answer to this question: if I have a table Matches with columns "homeTeam_id" and "awayTeam_id", and I want to add 2 teams to a match. How can I do that? Just using e.g. Teams.findById(1).add(new Team("Real Madrid")); doesn't work since there is no association. So how can I add a home team and an away team?

Comment: @TehSwish, this comment is unrelated to the question. Please, submit a new question and provide all the relevant details, including DDL of your tables;